# Elastic beanstalk Nigix Configuration for Golang app

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am following standard EBS config structure to override NGINX configuration as below. **.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/rate-limit.conf** **.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/error429.conf**

Not able to see the changes after deployment. Even when I SSH to the respective ec2 I dont see the expected files in

**/etc/nginx/ or /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/**

folder structure -
.ebextensions
.elasticbeanstalk
 main.go
 ... ...etc

Comment: `.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/rate-limit.conf` is correct. Probably some zipping issue? or file permission issue?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Go or programming, this is an AWS question entirely - try ServerFault.